# Best way to track user logs?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to build a user logs table that tracks the insertion, updates, deletion of data in my website. My challenge is to log the specific changes in my database.

For example:

I have a users table. I updated the password, the log should be like this

> "The user [username here] updated tblUsers.
> Changes:
>  Old Password: **password** - New Password: **password123**"

so far here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ASUSERLOGS
( 
  USERCD CHAR(15), //this is the username who changed something
  LOGTYPE CHAR(100), //logtype can be insert, delete, update, login, logout
  LOGDATE DATE, //date of the log
  LOG CHAR(2000),//here is where to insert the specific details of the log
  DATABASENAME  CHAR(20), //what database the user accessed
);
```

Is there a better way/efficient way to track specific changes in my database and have the old value and the new value?

Comment: I'm know it's just an example. but you shouldn't be storing plain text passwords anywhere

Comment: @rjdown yes its just an example for simplicity

Comment: I'd probably create a custom PDO class, override `prepare()` and `statement->execute` (something I've not done before), and on prepare I'd log the mysql statement to the database or a log file. And for the values I'd json_encode them & add them to the database/log file as well. I've never done this before. Just an untested idea.

Comment: But I have privacy concerns regarding keeping long-term logs like that. If someone changes their first/last name or email in their profile & you have a record of their prior first/last name & your database gets cracked then their old information is exposed.

Comment: you want a logfile, or you want to track it in your database ?

Comment: @MaxMuster track it in my database

Comment: then you do not use UPDATE in your script but for every move your users make, you make a new entry with INSERT, and when somebody change something you do simple make a new entry and a "modified_date" field next to it, and when you write your selects you simple select always the entry that has the newest date. do not forget to set your indexes properly or you will get crazy.

Comment: @MaxMuster what if there is a primary key?

Comment: @MaxMuster what if there is a primary key?

Comment: witch column is the primary key ? you can use a primary key that would be another column like userID that has the primary key, but you do not need ti just if you want to use indexing for faster finding of the entries

Comment: @MaxMuster will that be taxing on the database? The data will be so large

Comment: @MaxMuster will that be taxing on the database? The data will be so large

Comment: You want to log in the database. OK, you can limit the log files to 365 days or such. I lost complete the topic. We can talk here: https://t.me/ecxod